# Java get() changes initialized Hashtable keys to Null

Tags: java, hashtable

I'm currently having a problem with the get() method used with hashtables.

My initialization code:

```
        Hashtable<Integer, pageEntry> pageTable = new Hashtable<Integer, pageEntry>();
        Hashtable<Integer, LinkedList<Integer>> lookAhead = new Hashtable<Integer, LinkedList<Integer>();

        //Initialize pageTable and co.
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            pageEntry p = new pageEntry();
            pageTable.put(i, p);
            lookAhead.put(i, new LinkedList<Integer>());
        }
```

when I use `System.out.println(lookAhead);`, the output is as follows:

```
{0=[]}
{1=[], 0=[]}
{2=[], 1=[], 0=[]}
{3=[], 2=[], 1=[], 0=[]}
{4=[], 3=[], 2=[], 1=[], 0=[]}
```

If I use `System.out.println(lookAhead.get(0))`, the output is as follows

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

However, if I use `System.out.println(lookAhead.get(3))`, the output changes to

```
null
null
null
[]
[]
```

Is there some reason I'm overlooking as to why it changes my values to null?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

The `get` method returns `null` when the key is not present in the map.

In the first 3 iterations, the key is not present in the map. It's added on the 4th iteration, and the output shows a value associated with the key from the 4th iteration onwards.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. If this is the case, I'm still confused about why ```.get(0)``` would add the keys right away and ```get(3)``` would add them on the fourth?

Comment: You are adding a table entry with key 0 on the first iteration, with key 1 on the second iteration, and so on. That's why the entry for key 0 exists from the start, and in general the entry for key N does not exist until iteration N+1.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you accessed `lookAhead.get(3)`

When you use `lookAhead.get(0)`, the program is printing the empty linkedlists which were initialized to the index '0' in your HashTable.

You would have accessed the index location 3 (`lookAhead.get(3)`) without initializing at all. So, the program is printing null for non existent keys.